# How to create a dll starting from a CMake project

Tags: c++, qt

I have a c++ project Unix based that I need to convert into a dll usable on Windows. It is configured using CMake as a builder. I've compiled the project on Qt Creator using MinGW and verified that the application works correctly. The application also uses external dlls.

At this point I wondered: is there a way to create a dll from it?

Comment: A DLL is a *shared library* on Windows. If you can create a shared library on other platforms, then you should be able to create a DLL as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Fair point, but turning an ELF executable into a shared library is a reasonable question on its own.

Comment: @Foraz: A major difference between Unix shared libraries and Windows DLL's is that Windows uses the "nothing exported by default" model. Do you know which functions you want to export? You can't just rename `main` to `DllMain` and expect something reasonable to happen.